# Cannot import models to signals.py or tasks.py (django)

Tags: python, django

I'm having trouble importing models in my Django apps.
my app API is installed and migrated and visible in the admin I can add records through admin so the model is working.

for some reason when I try to import the model to `signals.py` to I get an error
I'm using Django 2.0

signals.py is located in the same directory as the model. Has Django changed the way you import models? I was under the impression that was the way.

> File "c:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/mbapi/api/signals.py", line 5, in
>   
>       from api import testModel ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api

signals.py

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, pre_delete, post_save, 
post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from api.models import testModel



@receiver(post_save, sender=testModel)
def update(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if instance.status == 'inplay':
        print('this is inplay')
        send()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class testModel(models.Model):     
    player1 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    player2 = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    Player1_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
    Player2_odds = models.FloatField(null=True)
    status = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)
    complete = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=50)

class inplay_model(models.Model):
    now_inplay = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=10)
```

stack trace

```
    (venv) C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\mbapi>c:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/mbapi/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/mbapi/api/signals.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/mbapi/api/signals.py", line 5, in <module>
        from api.models import testModel
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'

    (venv) C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\mbapi>
```

Comment: This error log message does not match your pasted code. Can you show full error log?

Comment: Why not just use `from .models import testModel`? That ways your import will be independent of app name.

Comment: @Paandittya when I try that I get a different error here. 

(venv) C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\mbapi>c:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/mbapi/venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/mbapi/api/signals.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/mbapi/api/signals.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .models import testModel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you have not accidentally deleted any __init__.py files OR tweaked any django generated file?

Comment: @Paandittya all the init.py files there

Comment: Class names should follow the `UpperCaseCamelCase` convention

Answer (score 0):

You already imported your `TestModel` in first line:

`from api.models import TestModel`

Line causing error tries to import `testModel` from app root:

`from api import testModel`

just remove it.

Comment: I have removed the second import but I have the same error.

Comment: @tomoc4 look for other import lines you didn't list in your question which do `from api import...`. In case there's something wrong with your `models.py` error should've changed to `No module named 'api.models'` but it didn't so it should be something else.

Comment: @ Kyryl Havrylenko I have just posted the full stacktrace. I've seen a similar question here could it be this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108694/django-signals-file-cannot-import-model-names

Comment: @tomoc4 it could be if you have imported signals in your `models.py`. Even updated question doesn't have contents of `models.py`

Comment: models.py is added to question

Answer (score 0):

The import issue will most likely be because you're missing `C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/mbapi/` in your (`sys.path`)

It seems that you're running the file directly. While possible, it's not very useful to run each file by itself when working with Django.

Django is better suited for the [runserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#runserver) command to make sure the `PATH` is set properly for you and all files needed are run.

If you then want to test your function, I suggest getting a basic [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/) setup (e.g. `http://localhost:8000/testapi`) or something in the apps `urls` and have the view simply run quick test code as you get used to the tools.

To assert that the import is working just fine you can simply add a print *after* the import and use `python manage.py runserver`. You should see the print while the startup code runs (*Note:* you'll need to have something importing the `signals.py` file like the `app.py` under the `def ready(self):` function.